# How to validate a XML

Tags: xml, validation, go, xml-parsing

I am new to Go and I am trying to validate XML, but I am not able to do it. Below is what I have tried but it's not working. Is there any way to do it.

```
func ParseXml(xml_path string) {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open(xml_path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } 
    // defer the closing of our xmlFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer xmlFile.Close()
    // read our opened xmlFile1 as a byte array. here I am checking if the file is valid or not
    byteValue, err := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s file reading failed \n",xml_path))
    } 
}
```

Although I am passing an invalid XML file, but I am not getting panic after

```
    byteValue, err := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
```

Comment: Please include all relevant error messages. If you don't receive an error, what output do you expect, and what do you see instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't validate XML syntax. Your code reads a file regardless of what it does. Easiest way to validate XML is with the `xml` package.

```
func IsValidXML(data []byte) bool {
    return xml.Unmarshal(data, new(interface{})) == nil
}
```

So regarding your code, it should become like so :

```
func ParseXml(xml_path string) {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open(xml_path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } 
    // defer the closing of our xmlFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer xmlFile.Close()
    // read our opened xmlFile1 as a byte array. here I am checking if the file is valid or not
    byteValue, err := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s file reading failed \n",xml_path))
    }

    if !IsValidXML(byteValue) {
        panic("Invalid XML has been input")
    }
}
```

For documentation of `xml.Unmarshal`, visit https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal

Comment: I think there's an error in the function `IsValidXML()` above; it should be `==`

Comment: Note that this is at most a check that the document is "well formed" XML.  Validation generally refers to the process of checking whether the document conforms to a schema.

Comment: @EB2127 true, i have a problem with conditions ngl lol

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, you cannot just use `xml.Unmarshal`, because this stops parsing after the first element has been closed. Example:

```
func IsValid(s string) bool {
    return xml.Unmarshal([]byte(s), new(interface{})) == nil
}

func main() {
    // Prints "true".
    fmt.Println(IsValid("<foo></foo><<<<<<<"))
}
```

You can, however, repeatedly decode elements until a non-io.EOF error occurs:

```
func IsValid(input string) bool {
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))
    for {
        err := decoder.Decode(new(interface{}))
        if err != nil {
            return err == io.EOF
        }
    }
}
```