# I need to validate whether a input string is in proper xml format using golang. My code doesn't validate if it has proper enclosing tags or not

Tags: xml, go, validation

```
if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), new(interface{})); err != nil {
        ve.Add("eav", "must be a valid xml")
    }
```

but it doesn't throw error when i pass a string like

```
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
```

I want it to throw error.

I tried this code

```
if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), new(interface{})); err != nil {
        ve.Add("eav", "must be a valid xml")
    }
```

Comment: here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476012/how-to-validate-a-xml

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks for sharing. But that solution doesn't work and is similar to what i have

Comment: string you've shared is valid xml, it will pass. take a look : https://go.dev/play/p/LKVuN-aWOYe

Comment: @Abhishek This is not a valid xml as per online validators. I checked at https://jsonformatter.org/xml-validator.
It gives error :
Invalid XML: This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: @ankitjain you are right. this is not a valid XML, because a root element missing.

Comment: I don't see in documentation that the xml-Unmarshal method guarantees XML-conform validation. Unmarshal just parses the XML-encoded data and stores the result in the pointed value. in your case interface{} as targeting is probably „too generic“.

Try to describe your xml as a valid xml structure and use it instead of "new(interface{})". Here is a good example: https://gobyexample.com/xml

Answer (score 0):

It does seem rather strange that `xml.Unmarshal` doesn't check that xml is well-formed - after all, xml that isn't well-formed isn't really xml at all.

However, using `xml.Decoder` it is possible to check for some non-well-formed issues (such as multiple or missing root elements)...

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    testCases := map[string]string{
        "valid":                   `<root><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from></root>`,
        "multiple roots":          `<to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from>`,
        "empty":                   ``,
        "no root":                 `<?xml version='1.0'?>`,
        "valid xml decl":          `<?xml version='1.0'?><root/>`,
        "invalid pi name":         `<root><?Xml pi name cannot be xml?></root>`,
        "xml decl inside root":    `<root><?xml version='1.0'?></root>`,
        "multiple xml decls":      `<?xml version='1.0'?><?xml version='1.0'?><root/>`,
        "comment before xml decl": `<!-- comment --><?xml version='1.0'?><root/>`,
        "cdata before xml decl":   `<![CDATA[text]]><?xml version='1.0'?><root/>`,
    }
    for name, str := range testCases {
        if err := checkXmlWellFormed(strings.NewReader(str)); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("'%s' error: %s\n", name, err.Error())
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("'%s' is well-formed xml\n", name)
        }
    }
}

func checkXmlWellFormed(r io.Reader) error {
    d := xml.NewDecoder(r)
    d.Strict = true
    var err error
    var token xml.Token
    var finalErr error
    depth := 0
    rootFound := false
    xmlDeclFound := false
    pastProlog := false
    for err == nil && finalErr == nil {
        token, err = d.Token()
        if err == nil {
            switch tt := token.(type) {
            case xml.StartElement:
                pastProlog = true
                if depth == 0 {
                    if rootFound {
                        finalErr = errors.New("too many root elements")
                    } else {
                        rootFound = true
                    }
                }
                depth++
            case xml.EndElement:
                pastProlog = true
                depth--
            case xml.ProcInst:
                if tt.Target == "xml" {
                    if xmlDeclFound {
                        finalErr = errors.New("multiple xml declarations")
                    } else if pastProlog {
                        finalErr = errors.New("xml declaration must be first")
                    }
                    xmlDeclFound = true
                } else if strings.ToUpper(tt.Target) == "XML" {
                    finalErr = fmt.Errorf("invalid processing instruction name '%s'", tt.Target)
                }
            case xml.CharData:
                if depth < 1 {
                    finalErr = errors.New("character data outside element")
                }
                pastProlog = true
            default:
                pastProlog = true
            }
        } else if err != io.EOF {
            finalErr = err
        }
    }
    if finalErr == nil && !rootFound {
        finalErr = errors.New("no root element")
    }
    return finalErr
}
```

[try on go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/xqHdwZNs4HD)

With a moderate amount of effort, it would also be possible to check for adequate namespace declarations - something else that `xml.Decoder` / `xml.Unmarshal` doesn't check :(